# Test-Drive ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm starting to work on a new project that uses ASP.NET MVC 3. A friend of mine owns the book Test-Drive ASP.NET MVC by Johnathan McCracken, but this book covers ASP.NET MVC version 2.

Anyone knows if I'm going to have lots of trouble because of the version difference? Is this book too outdated?

Thank you.

Comment: Why start with MVC 3? Use 4. It makes no sense to start a new project on outdated code.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. However, the project is already done and it was made with MVC 3.

Comment: The biggest difference will be the view engine, assuming that is what the MVC 3 project you'll be working on is using.  MVC 3 introduced the razor engine which looks *a lot* different than the old asp view engine.  If I were you I'd skip the book and just go to http://asp.net/mvc and read/work through one or two of their tutorials for a nice overview and introduction to the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely learn using an ASP.Net MVC 2 book, as much of the framework is the same.

However, as others have noted, the biggest difference you will notice is with the 'View Engine'.  Most examples now use the 'Razor' engine, as opposed to the old version 2 View Engine (I don't know if it actually had a name) which is cumbersome and ugly by comparison.

So you could learn using your version 2 book, and learn the Razor view from the web, but you might as well just start learning version 3 from any number of different web sites and save yourself the pain of all the angle brackets of the version 2 View Engine.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC builds on previous ASP.NET MVC versions. If your book is MVC 2, you should still be able to grasp the model-view-controller concept.

For a list of differences (additions introduced in MVC 3) see [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#overview):

> - Extensible Scaffolding with MvcScaffold integration
> - HTML 5 enabled project templates
> - The Razor View Engine
> - Support for Multiple View Engines
> - Controller Improvements
> - JavaScript and Ajax
> - Model Validation Improvements
> - Dependency Injection Improvements
> - Other New Features

Personally, the [Razor View Engine](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_TheRazorViewEngine) was quite useful for a project I had....especially vs `.aspx`.